# Not able to configure load balancer for Vm in azure

Tags: azure

I want to add traffic manager to my azure virtual machine.I created total 4 virtual machine .2 in east us region and 2 in north Europe region.but when i want to add the both 2nd machine in the availability set respectively i didn't find the other machine which i want to add.
so help me to configure this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Availability Sets and Traffic Manager are not related subjects in Azure.  When you create your two virtual machines in each Region make sure to add them to the same Cloud Service. This will enable load balancing and enforce availability set behaviour across the two VMs.

Repeat this in the second Region.

Then use Traffic Manager to route traffic using a Failover strategy (if appropriate) to the public interfaces of the Cloud Services.

While this is about using Web Roles you might find this blog series useful: http://blog.kloud.com.au/2014/11/03/deploy-an-ultra-high-availablity-mvc-web-app-on-microsoft-azure-part-1/

Comment: Really thank !! this works actually what i did i create every virtual machine in with their own cloud service that is why i were not able to see the other machine which is reside in the same region but not in the same cloud.

Answer (score 0):

Availability sets are not the same as the traffic manager.

Availability sets are per region (that's why you only see 2 machines)
Add a traffic manager through the portal and select the VM's in both regions.

http://michaelwasham.com/windows-azure-powershell-reference-guide/understanding_configuring_availability_sets_powershell/

https://alexandrebrisebois.wordpress.com/2013/07/23/windows-azure-traffic-manager-high-performance-availability-resiliency/